# Flysystem file not found when deleting

Tags: php, laravel, flysystem

I'm trying to delete a photo with Laravel 5.

```
Storage::delete( asset('/uploads/slides/abcd.jpg'));
```

Its returning this error:

```
FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 428:
File not found at path: http:/localhost:8000/uploads/slides/abcd.jpg
```

If I copy and paste the path in the browser it opens the file so the file really exists. Whats wrong?

Comment: What does the function asset() do?  I can't find it in the offical documentation.

Comment: It returns "http:/localhost:8000/"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to change the root path in config/filesystem.php because it was looking the file in the old defined path (the storage path)

This is the modified version

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path(),
    ],
]
```